# ajax onlick button only works on second click

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I made a button that serves to increase the quantity of a product, and at the same time increases the sizes of products and this works fine. But i have a ajax request that calculates the price of the product and add a value to shipping, but for some reason, it only works in the second click, ignoring the first one and the calculation.

my html page:

In my controller i have a @if that if the price goes above 30€ it change the value of portes, and that changes after the second click only.

```
<li id="portes"><span><strong> Portes: </strong></span><span>@if(Cart::getSubTotal() ==
                                0){{ 0 . ' €' }}@else{{ number_format($envioPortes, 2)  . ' €' }}@endif</span>
                        </li>
```

my main.js:

```
function plusqty(id) {

let qty = $('#qty' + id).val();

$('#qty' + id).val(parseInt(qty) + 1);

let qtyupdated = $('#qty' + id).val();

$.ajax({
    url: "/cart-update",
    type: "POST",
    data: {
        id: id,
        quantity: qtyupdated,
        'cobranca': $('#cobranca_check').prop("checked")
    },
    async: true,
    success: function (response) {

        Swal.fire({
            title: "Quantidade atualizada com sucesso",
            background: '#f74877',
            position: 'center',
            toast: true,
            allowEscapeKey: false,
            showCloseButton: false,
            showConfirmButton: false,
            timer: 1000,
        });

        $('.cart_holder').html(response.cart);
        $('.modalQty' + id).html($('#qty' + id).val());
        $("#modalSubTotal").text(response.subTotalModal);
    },
    error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {}
});
```

}

my 3 buttons, i can add and put some quantity manually:

```
<td class="column-4">
                        <div class="wrap-num-product flex-w m-l-auto m-r-0">
                            <button type="button" class="btn-num-product-down cl8 trans-04 flex-c-m qtyA"
                                onclick="minusqty({{ $product->id }})">
                                <i class="fs-16 zmdi zmdi-minus"></i>
                            </button>

                            <input class="mtext-104 cl3 txt-center num-product quantity-amount{{$product->id}}"
                                type="text" name="num-product" oninput="manualqty({{ $product->id }})"
                                value="{{ $product->quantity }}">

                            <button type="button" class="btn-num-product-up cl8 trans-04 flex-c-m qtyA"
                                onclick="plusqty({{ $product->id }})">
                                <i class="fs-16 zmdi zmdi-plus"></i>
                            </button>
                            <input type="hidden" class="hidden" id="qty{{$product->id}}"
                                value="{{ $product->quantity }}">
                        </div>
```

Tks!

Comment: Where is your button function?

Comment: @A.ANoman, sry! added

Comment: `minusqty` or `plusqty` which one is correct??

Comment: May be you want like this https://nitolelectronics.com/product/58

Comment: sorry, i explained myself badly. these buttons are working fine, but I have an ajax request to calculate shipping called shipping, and this ajax request is the one that ignores the first click and only calculates it on the 2nd time, gonna try to edit better

Comment: No need `async: true,`

Comment: i tried that before, nothing change, but i will take it off anyway, tks!